# How to split a table in SQL Server into two different related tables inserting foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, temporary-tables

I have a table `OriginTable` with the following structure

```
EventID | Date       | Value1     | Value2     | Value3
-----------------------------------------------------------
5       | 2019-10-07 | MyValue1_1 | MyValue2_1 | MyValue3_1
5       | 2019-10-07 | MyValue1_2 | MyValue2_2 | MyValue3_2
5       | 2019-10-07 | MyValue1_3 | MyValue2_3 | MyValue3_3
6       | 2019-10-07 | MyValue1_4 | MyValue2_4 | MyValue3_4
6       | 2019-10-07 | MyValue1_5 | MyValue2_5 | MyValue3_5
6       | 2019-10-07 | MyValue1_6 | MyValue2_6 | MyValue3_6
```

where `EventID` is reinitiated every day, but the combination of EventID and Date values provides a suitable unique identifier.

I want to split this table into two tables `FirstDestinationTable` and `SecondDestinationTable` like

```
ID | EventID | Date
-------------------------
1  | 5       | 2019-10-07
2  | 6       | 2019-10-07
```

and

```
FirstDstTblID | Value1     | Value2     | Value3
----------------------------------------------------
1             | MyValue1_1 | MyValue2_1 | MyValue3_1
1             | MyValue1_2 | MyValue2_2 | MyValue3_2
1             | MyValue1_3 | MyValue2_3 | MyValue3_3
2             | MyValue1_4 | MyValue2_4 | MyValue3_4
2             | MyValue1_5 | MyValue2_5 | MyValue3_5
2             | MyValue1_6 | MyValue2_6 | MyValue3_6
```

where `FirstDstTblID` references `FirstDestinationTable(ID)`.

The purpose of this task is to save storage space since `OriginTable` is 120MB each day and I want to execute this on a daily basis.

Thanks.

Comment: That's approx 1GB/week. A 1 TB disk will last 20 years before running out of space. Why go to the trouble if your design works? Your time and effort are worth more than some disk space! p.s welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Vérace. The SQL Database is stored in Azure and I have to insert at least seven years of such data, moreover the company aims for storage cost optimization. Plus, the data analysis that I'm developing for it will be quicker and easier if table is splitted.

Comment: "the combination of values from columns EventID and Date is unique across all rows" - not in your sample data it's not.

Comment: If the intention is to save space on-disk investigate the [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-2017) compression options.

Comment: @JorgeCatumbaRuiz  just saw eventID and date being unique. If that is the case, splitting it off will actually increase storage space.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you will save any storage space by splitting the attributes into two tables. INT uses 4 bytes of storage space.  A date uses 3 bytes. Say you compress down a million rows to just one value. ( Ex There are 1 Million rows that have the combination of Event ID 5 and date 2019-10-07). You will save a total of 3 million bytes. That's only 3 megabytes.

You could technically do the same thing you want on the other side of the table; split off every combination of MyValue, create a look up table of them, and then join each on a third table. But don't!

Readability and maintenance are things to consider along side just storage cost. So is your time developing this solution. The current 10/7/2019 cost for Azure SQL database storage (past your 32gb of free data) is $0.138/GB/Month. After 3 years of every week gaining a full GB of data(Total storage is now 156gb), you will have only spent a TOTAL of $1,679.18.

Answer (score 0):

Do it step-by-step (assuming destination tables are new/empty):

```sql
INSERT INTO FirstDestinationTable (EventID, "Date")
SELECT DISTINCT EventID, "Date" 
FROM OriginTable;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO SecondDestinationTable (FirstDstTblID, Value1, Value2, Value3)
SELECT f.ID, o.Value1, o.Value2, o.Value3
FROM FirstDestinationTable f
JOIN OriginTable o ON f.EventID = o.EventID AND f."Date" = o."Date"
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9321b7049b90dc6f31a920482d1c2b8)